# Difference between various layouts using in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I want a conceptual level approach why we are using linear,relative,frame and absolute layout for different aspects.What I understood is

1.LinearLayout - For placing different controls one by one, also both vertical and horizontal orientation possible

2.RelativeLayout - Placing the controls relative to other

3.FrameLayout -Placeholder on screen that you can use to display in one view.

4.AbsoluteLayout -Place controls exact location of its children

5.TableLayout- Place views into rows and columns

I need experts suggestions and **need to know more about layouts** both for **android device and tablets.**

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why negative vote for my question. I want to clear my concept!!

Comment: As it stands, your question is very open-ended and would not have a clear answer. Stack Overflow, as I'm sure you know by now, is for specific questions and answers. [Here is a good tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/) of various layouts, and the documentation is also very clear on what to use in various circumstances. Just **do not use `AbsoluteLayout`**, it's been deprecated for almost 5 years now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extracting Eric's [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/), adding as an answer.

The most commonly used layout classes are:

- FrameLayout – designed to display a stack of child View controls. Multiple view controls can be added to this layout. This can be used to show multiple controls within the same screen space.
  I'll call it a 'Hide-and-seek' layout. Was commonly used for Tabs.
- LinearLayout – designed to display child View controls in a single row or column. This is a very handy layout method for creating forms.
  A straight layout. Easy to maintain, but bit hard to design.
- RelativeLayout – designed to display child View controls in relation to each other. For instance, you can set a control to be positioned “above” or “below” or “to the left of” or “to the right of” another control, referred to by its unique identifier. You can also align child View controls relative to the parent edges.
  Easy to design, but bit hard to maintain.
- TableLayout – designed to organize child View controls into rows and columns. Individual View controls are added within each row of the table using a TableRow layout View (which is basically a horizontally oriented LinearLayout) for each row of the table.
- Also, hava a look at [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html). GridView is a ViewGroup that displays items in a two-dimensional, scrollable grid. Very useful in Gallery like UI.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. ur effort is appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks it's nice post, i have doubt which is layout is preferable and can we use one layout in another ?.... I just started working on android ...